# Azure B2C integration with PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Hope you can help with, we are building a new customer portal and would like to use Azure B2C for various reasons including the need to interface with MS Dynamics CE. However, our tech stack is PHP, Slim to be precise.

Does anyone have experience of delivering a fully functioning production app with this configuration?

Would love to hear from you and have your assistance.

Please get in touch.

Thanks, Duong.

Comment: Please refer [PHP Web Application with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect/blob/main-deprecated/README.md#php-web-application-with-azure-ad-b2c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To deploy the PHP Web Application using Azure AD B2C,follow the below  steps :**

- Install PHP, Laravel (it's web framework).
- Create a Web App in Azure Portal B2C blade by noting the ClientID and Client Secret from the Application.
- Clone and customize the source code from github: `git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect.git`
- Download the latest version of the ***php security library*** in your repo.
- To deploy into Azure, you need to set-up the Deployment settings by selecting Local Git Repository and setting up the username and password for deployment.
- `git init` and `git remote add azure [deployment url]` commands are used to set up deployment to azure.
- `git push azure master` to deploy online.
- Instead of depending on their own code, developers can rely on B2C for consumer sign up and sign in.
- Using OpenID Connect, we can validate the authentication token of the users connected with the Azure B2C of the PHP Web Application.

**Please refer this [GitHub article](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect/blob/main-deprecated/README.md#php-web-application-with-azure-ad-b2c) for code and more information.**

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented B2C integration on Azure with a Slim 4 application, what is it you need to know?

In short:

1. Set up B2C in Azure
2. Set up Client ID en Secret in external provider and store in Azure Key Vault
3. Create a middleware service that looks for the client token in requests for the routes you want to protect

I haven't written a blog about it yet, but expect one in March at [www.azurephp.dev](https://www.azurephp.dev/) with a working example using Slim 4. In the mean time, I hope this short answer works for you. If not, ping me.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond. I will discuss with my team and will let you know how we get on. Best regards, Duong.

Comment: Ok @DTran, let me know how I can help