# Azure B2C with OpenID Connect and PKCE

Tags: php, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to make an Azure B2C login with Laravel, I'm halfway there right now.

The Laravel part is an API, and the client is in Angular. I've planned to make the whole process on the BE. When a user clicks "Sign in with Microsoft" to be redirected to the BE server-side page and I do the magic on the BE. In the end, I want to make a redirect to some FE page and set the access token in the cookie.

I've defined two web.php (server-side) routes. The first one is for redirecting away to the Azure login and the second one is for a callback.

Here is the code:

```
public function redirect()
{
    $length = mt_rand(43, 128);
    $bytes = random_bytes($length);
    $codeVerifier = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($bytes), '+/', '-_'), '=');

    $state = Str::random(40);

    $query = http_build_query([
        'p' => 'B2C_1A_SIGNIN',
        'client_id' => config('services.azureadb2c.client_id'),
        'redirect_uri' => config('services.azureadb2c.redirect'),
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'openid',
        'state' => $state,
        'prompt' => 'login',
        'code_challenge' => $this->generateCodeChallenge($codeVerifier),
        'code_challenge_method' => 'S256',
    ]);

    session(['state' => $state, 'code_verifier' => $codeVerifier]);

    return redirect('https://' . config('services.azureadb2c.domain') . '.b2clogin.com/' . config('services.azureadb2c.domain') . '.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?' . $query);
}

public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->post("https://" . config('services.azureadb2c.domain') . ".b2clogin.com/" . config('services.azureadb2c.domain') . ".onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1A_SIGNIN", [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => config('services.azureadb2c.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => config('services.azureadb2c.client_secret'),
            'code' => $request->get('code'),
            'redirect_uri' => config('services.azureadb2c.redirect'),
            'code_verifier' => session('code_verifier'),
            'scope' => 'openid',
        ],
    ]);
    var_dump(json_decode($response->body()));
    exit;
}

private function generateCodeChallenge($codeVerifier) {
    $hash = hash('sha256', $codeVerifier, true);
    $codeChallenge = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($hash), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    return $codeChallenge;
}
```

Here, I'm facing the next problem. Redirect is working well, the user is redirected properly and he can enter the credentials well and everything. At the end in the callback, I receive the authorization code, but when I make a POST request to get the access token I get the next error

```
`400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADB2C90085: The service has encountered an internal error. Please reauthe (truncated...)
```

Do you have any idea what can cause this error?

Comment: Have you seen and tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139597/azure-b2c-integration-with-php ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I've seen this example but it's not related to my use case. This example contains an implicit flow that returns an access token without an authorization code. In my case, I want to make a login with OpenID Connect and PKCE.

Comment: The error you received indicates that the 'scope' that you supplied is not sufficient to get back the id token.

Comment: @Anand thanks. What should I do to try to fix it? The only supported scope is "openid" and I'm using it. Here I don't receive the ID token. In the first step, I receive only the authorization code and then I'm passing that to get the access token.

Comment: Try passing the client id also as one scope value along with `openid`, just a clue from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-an-access-token

Comment: it didn't help, I tried various variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD B2C application by selecting **SPA** in redirect URIs like below:

[image]

I ran below c# code by Bac Hoang [MSFT] from this [blog](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/08/performing-azure-ad-oauth2-authorization-code-grant-flow-with-pkce-in-postman/) and got values of `code_challenge` and `code_verifier` successfully as below:

```cs
using IdentityModel;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
 
namespace PKCEConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            int cvlength = random.Next(43, 128);
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~";
            var codeVerifier = new string (Enumerable.Repeat(chars, cvlength).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
 
            string codeChallenge;
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                var a = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier);
                var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
                codeChallenge = Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
            }
 
            Console.WriteLine("codeVerifier " + codeVerifier + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("codeChallenge " + codeChallenge + "\n");
 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I ran below authorization request in browser and got **code** successfully like this:

```
https://sritenantb2c.b2clogin.com/sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=742978eb-ccb4-4b82-8140-3526417d4d09
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid
&code_challenge=l-kik2UPt2cInWJK6liasiRBhdpNm3qeOqUma_4Ih7E
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to generate tokens via Postman with below parameters, I got only `id_token` and `refresh_token` without **access token** like below:

```http
POST https://sritenantb2c.b2clogin.com/sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:742978eb-ccb4-4b82-8140-xxxxxxxxxx
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid
code: <paste code from above step>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:hMl0zyCvyUKJxS1gjOPqFNf1LPQ~tcvekFJeWsfzFGSFMi5~QkpCAq1QHMDT3N
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get access token, add new scope by **exposing an API** like below:

[image]

Now, add this `scope` in your application that will come under **Delegated** permissions like below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to the above scope like below:

[image]

Now, generate **`code`** again by running below authorization request in browser like this

```
https://sritenantb2c.b2clogin.com/sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=742978eb-ccb4-4b82-8140-xxxxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com/742978eb-ccb4-4b82-8140-xxxxxxxxxx/.default
&code_challenge=l-kik2UPt2cInWJK6liasiRBhdpNm3qeOqUma_4Ih7E
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

**Response:**

[image]

I generated **access token** successfully using below parameters via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://sritenantb2c.b2clogin.com/sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signin/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:742978eb-ccb4-4b82-8140-xxxxxxxxxx
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: https://sritenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com/742978eb-ccb4-4b82-8140-xxxxxxxxxxx/Admin.Read openid
code: <paste code from above step>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:hMl0zyCvyUKJxS1gjOPqFNf1LPQ~tcvekFJeWsfzFGSFMi5~QkpCAq1QHMDT3N
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/), I got the **`scp`** claim like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the problem was in sending the client_secret in the request, when I've deleted that param like in your example then it worked.